# ORACLE SQL TRIGGERS: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

Hello I am getting the error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following
I cannot find the reason for this error please help me.  Thanks

**EDIT**: correct code pasted

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SUNSHINE_DEPT"
BEFORE INSERT ON "PURCHASE"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE type VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN 

    SELECT SERVICETYPE INTO type 
    FROM (
      SELECT P.SERVICETYPE, D.DNAME
      FROM DEPT D JOIN EMP E ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO JOIN PURCHASE P ON E.EMPNO = P.SERVEDBY
      WHERE D.DNAME = 'SALES - Sunshine' AND P.SERVEDBY IN (:NEW.SERVEDBY));

    IF type = 'Data Recovery' THEN
      :NEW.AMOUNT := :NEW.AMOUNT * 0.7;
    END IF;
    :NEW.PAYMENTTYPE := 'Cash';
END;
/
```

Comment: Presumably the statement actually  tarts with `create trigger`, not with `before insert`.

Comment: Yes I will edit it now my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE type VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN
```

`type` is a [reserved word in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm). You would need to use another name for the variable.

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aba2dba989adddea443f80d9a3e5b4f2)**, the trigger compiles successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SUNSHINE_DEPT"
BEFORE INSERT ON "PURCHASE"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE mytype VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN 

    SELECT SERVICETYPE INTO mytype 
    FROM (
      SELECT P.SERVICETYPE, D.DNAME
      FROM DEPT D JOIN EMP E ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO JOIN PURCHASE P ON E.EMPNO = P.SERVEDBY
      WHERE D.DNAME = 'SALES - Sunshine' AND P.SERVEDBY IN (:NEW.SERVEDBY));

    IF mytype = 'Data Recovery' THEN
      :NEW.AMOUNT := :NEW.AMOUNT * 0.7;
    END IF;
    :NEW.PAYMENTTYPE := 'Cash';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does not look correct:

```
SELECT SERVICETYPE INTO type
FROM (SELECT P.SERVICETYPE, D.DNAME
      FROM DEPT D JOIN
           EMP E
           ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO JOIN
           PURCHASE P
           ON E.EMPNO = P.SERVEDBY
      WHERE D.DNAME = 'SALES - Sunshine'
     ) AND P.SERVEDBY IN (:NEW.SERVEDBY);
```

The `)` before the `AND` should be moved after the last condition.

`IN` with a column is also suspicious.  That would not however result in a compilation error, just unexpected behavior at runtime.

Comment: I have corrected the code, had pasted an earlier version accidently